# Can I convert a dmg file to iso in terminal?

Tags: 12.04

I use dmg2img to convert a dmg file. What package will convert a dmg 2 iso?

Answer (score 34):

Follow the steps below.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install dmg2img
```

Once installed, run the following command:

```
dmg2img <file_name>.dmg
```

That will convert the .dmg to ,img file in ISO format. Then just run

```
mv <file_name>.img <file_name>.iso
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this leaves you with an apple img file; `file InstallESD.iso` returns `Apple Driver Map`, and I can't open it as an iso.

Comment: What are you using to open the ISO file?

Comment: @bukzor works fine for me with `sudo mount file.iso emptydirectoryname`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to convert the dmg to iso you need:

**1) Convert the dmg to img using dmg2img**

you can install it using:
`sudo apt-get install dmg2img`

Then (if your dmg is named image.dmg in the current folder):

`dmg2img image.dmg image.img`

**2) To mount the img**

`mkdir /media/image`

`sudo modprobe hfsplus`

`sudo mount -t hfsplus -o loop image.img /media/image`

**3) To burn the files in /media/image coming from the mount to an iso file:**

You may use brasero for that step.
You can install it using:

`sudo apt-get install brasero`

Detailed instructions can be found there:
http://dailytechnologiesupdate.blogspot.co.il/2011/11/converting-dmg-to-iso-file-in-ubuntu.html